# How do I run Jasmine tests for Angular 2 in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: angular, jasmine, karma-runner

I know that you can do a "karma start" from the command line and run all tests.  How do you run all tests from Visual Studio Code?  What if you are creating a test and need to debug the test in Visual Studio Code.  How would you do that?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I'm new in VSCode and cannot seem to find the answer to this.

Comment: I am no longer using Angular.  There is a Jasmine runner extension for Visual Studio Code.  I would try that.  Let me know if that is the answer.